# Multiselect drop down not cleared value after selecting other option

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I have two drop down lists,if I select value from first dropdown, id will be passed to second dropdown which is multiselect dropdown of Bootstrap .
The problem is if that id doesn't have record in database that shows previously selected values.

I have tried `.empty()`,refresh etc but it doesn't show the proper result.
Please help..
Code is below:

```
var ID = $("#AreaMasterID").val();
$.ajax({
      url: '../AllocateDump/FillDumpingSite',
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        "AreaMasterID": ID
      },
      async: false,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(res) {
        if (res.length == 0) {
          $("#DumpID").val('0');
          $("#DumpID").val(' ');
          //$("#DumpID").multiselect('refresh'); 
          // $("#DumpID option").remove();                        
          //$("#DumpID").multiselect('destroy');

        } else {
          for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            $("#DumpID").empty()
                        .append($("<option></option>")
                        .val(res[i].DumpingSiteID)
                        .html(res[i].DumpSiteName));
              }
              $('#DumpID').multiselect({
                includeSelectAllOption: true
              });
            }
            $("#DumpID").multiselect('refresh');
          },
          error: function(err) {
            $.kanNotify.error(err);
          },
        });
```

In span it display selected values which are not cleared by .empty() and other options.

[browser genrated html code view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCYNK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (let i = 0; i <= $('#DumpID option').length; i++) {
  $("#DumpID").remove(i);
}
```

Comment: not working.. actually value is not set to drop down Id i. e. DumpID , its set to see this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCYNK.png